# doctrine inheritance on manytoone

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Have two class with inheritance the mother :

the problems is doctrine doesn't create field on manytoone field on inheritance. I don't found any solution. I work with doctrine 2 ans Symfony 4

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TaskRepository")
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
 class Task
 {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"group2"})
     */
     protected $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      * @Groups({"group1", "group2"})
      */
     protected $user;
     ...
}
```

and the child:

```
 use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TaskHistoryRepository")
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="user",
 *          joinColumns=@ORM\JoinColumn(
 *              name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
 class TaskHistory extends Task
 {
     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task")
      */
     private $sourceTask;

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      * @Groups({"group1", "group2"})
      */
     protected $user;
     ...
}
```

My field user on child class was never created on my database. 
Whatever the configuration, is incredible. 
What is wrong ?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: This might help you http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses You need a MappedSuperclassBase and both your `Task` and `TaskHistory` classes should extend the MappedSuperclassBase. Both `$id` and `$user` properties should be in MappedSuperclassBase

Comment: Don't think it has to do with it, but you have the `@ORM\MappedSuperclass` twice in Task class ;)

Comment: taks is mappedsuperclass  and the id and user are in ... doc say you can use on entity class :) Yes I try to get any log or errors ... without is the same things .

Comment: Taken from docs: A mapped superclass is an abstract or concrete class that provides persistent entity state and mapping information for its subclasses, `but which is not itself an entity.` The mapped superclass cannot be an entity.

Comment: Samples are insidious in the doc ;)

Comment: What is the output of the command: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` ?

Comment: the schema is good ;)